# Access 2003: reorder list using drag-and-drop?

Tags: ms-access, drag-and-drop

This should be either simple or impossible.

In an Access 2003 database, entries in the Project table have fields Designer and Priority (and others). I'd like to list all the projects for one Designer in a list box or other control, in priority order (this much is easy), then let the Designer or her manager re-order the priorities using drag-and-drop. That part is harder since native drag-and-drop support is not incredibly strong.

I know that VBA for Access does allow me to define events for drag start, drag stop, etc.

I will not be adding any custom OLE objects or anything else that doesn't ship with Access--we've had huge deployment issues with custom controls in the past.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK There's no built in support for drag and drop, but I found a link that may or may not help you http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;233274

Comment: Thanks. I am in the process of writing my own form to do this, but I plan to use "move up" and "move down" arrows rather than drag-and-drop to simplify my coding. I do appreciate your taking the time.